# Springfox swagger inheritance support workaround

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-2.0, springfox

As of 2.7.0 SpringFox Swagger does not support inheritance:

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1983

I have an app that relies on the fact that swagger supports inheritance, but still need to update library to version 2.8.0.

Is it actually possible to provide backward compatibility for inheritance in a way (even dirty way)?

Would really appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Did you find a workaround ? I have the same issue. Share the details, if you have found any workaround. Thanks

Comment: Yes, Please share your workaround

Answer (score 1):

SpringFox Swagger 2.9.0 (latest version at the time of this post) introduced one part of the inheritance functionality.
so you can use smth like `@Apimodel(parent = MyParent.class)` to add `allof $ref` to the child, 
but this [version](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2457#issuecomment-395281507) doesn't support the `oneof $ref` for the parent class

My workaround was migrating to [springdoc open-api](https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html)

**parent class**

```
@Schema(oneOf = {Child1.class, Child2.class})
```

**child class**

```
@Schema(allOf = Parent.class)
```

Comment: Do we need ```@Schema(allOf = Parent.class)``` part? Instead can't we achieve the expected result with annotation on the parent class only?

Comment: @TharinduSathischandra this might work for you as well.. but the swagger spec defined the use of 2-way connections...